# qTip2 wrong position on rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip2

I'm trying to create a qtip containing a set of icomoon icons. My issue is that the first time the qtip is rendered, it appears displaced from where it's supposed to be.

The content is embedded in my html with `display: none` and, apparently, the icons are not rendered until after the qtip is created. Therefore, icons are not taken into account for defining the initial width of the qtip and this causes the wrong offset.

When displaying the qtip next times, it doesn't happen anymore as the icons are already rendered and then the width is calculated correctly.

I'm wondering if my approach is simply wrong and there is a more proper solution of defining the content of the tooltip, or hacks are my only option.

Here I have a that depicts my case:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omegak/6XxgB)

Comment: Your problem is: you have to display the tooltip two times to show the icons inside it?

Comment: First time, displaying the tooltip makes the icons to render. This happens after the qtip measures the width and sets its position. Then, the icons get rendered and enlarges the tooltip. This is the problem.

Second time, as the icons are already rendered, width and position are set correctly.

Comment: Are you using qTip on document ready or window loaded?

Comment: Try to load with window.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm. Please, convert your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading your qTip2 code when the document is ready, try to load with the window, like as follow:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   // Your code here
});
```